# Completely static linking with clang

Tags: c, gcc, linker, clang, llvm

How can I generate completely static binaries with clang? I have used the following command:

```
clang -flto <source files> -o <executable output> -fuse-ld=lld -static-libgcc -lc -Bstatic -m32
```

And yet, the generated output depends on a certain `.so` file:

```
$ ldd <executable output file>
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77dd000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf75f0000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x5663b000)
```

[The following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34463943/915843) tries to answer the question but doesn't directly address the problem.
**Is it even possible, to generate completely independent binaries?** Or should I have resort to using other different C library implementations other than `libgcc`?

If yes, then how do I link it with clang if I have the source code, of for example `newlib`?

Comment: `linux-gate.so` is the syscall interface and `ld-linux.so` is the ELF binary interpreter (See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981862/what-are-ld-linux-so-2-and-linux-gate-so-1). You might be able to get a statically linked version of `libc` but the others need to be there. This begs the question: "Why?" and "What is the ultimate purpose?" Unless you're doing a boot loader or some such ...

Comment: If you statically link `libc.so`, you usually get an executable that is *less* portable.

Comment: I am trying to make some analysis in my compiler, and I need completely independent binary for that.

Comment: Have you tried the -static option? You may find that some of the libraries you want are not available in a static form. You may be able to find static versions, or build them from source.

Comment: *I am trying to make some analysis in my compiler, and I need completely independent binary for that*  So this is an [XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  What *problem* in analyzing your compiler do you think a completely statically-linked binary solves?

Comment: It would be giving me the C standard library functions to my analysis in the compiler infrastructure. That is why I want to build a C standard library with Clang, so that I can analyse them.

Answer (score 5):

Just compile it using the clang's -static flag.

On your case, try:

```
clang -flto <source files> -o <executable output> -static -m32
```

The results on my test program show:

```
[root@interserver ogrerobot.com]# ldd ./CppUtilsSpikes  
not a dynamic executable
```

Answer (score 1):

If you, like me, got here expecting Darwin would behave somewhat similarly to Linux, [that unfortunately isn't the case](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1118/_index.html)

> Apple fully supports static libraries; if you want to create one, just
> start with the appropriate Xcode project or target template.
>
> Apple does not support statically linked binaries on Mac OS X. A
> statically linked binary assumes binary compatibility at the kernel
> system call interface, and we do not make any guarantees on that
> front. Rather, we strive to ensure binary compatibility in each
> dynamically linked system library and framework.